# Matrix Derivative of $ {L}_{1} $ Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I'm with problems to find step-by-step resolution for a matrix differentiation. My main problem is to solve the L1 norm into this derivative:

$\nabla K = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left | BCx - Nk + Fk \right |_{1}^{1} $

where B, C, N and F are matrix and x are a vector.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Shouldn't $N$ and $F$ be vectors instead of matrices?

Comment: You're rigth. I've forgot the others vectors..

Comment: Why do you want to compute the derivative?

Comment: That does not quite answer my question. If you want to minimize an objective function that uses the 1-norm, then use linear programming, not differentiation.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ok, I understand. Yes, I want to minimize that function.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5wNv.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, define a new vector variable 
$$y=BCx-Nk+Fk \implies dy=BC\,dx$$
Then 
$$\eqalign{
  K &= \|y\|_1 = {\rm sign}(y):y \cr
  dK &= {\rm sign}(y):dy = {\rm sign}(y):BC\,dx = (BC)^T{\rm sign}(y):dx \cr
\frac{\partial K}{\partial x} &= C^TB^T{\rm sign}(BCx-Nk+Fk) \cr
}$$
where colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, $A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$

and the ${\rm sign}$ function is applied elementwise to the vector argument.

The gradient is undefined when any component of $y$ equals zero.